# SQL Server - How do I query a table for matches with keywords from another table?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have two tables: **Job**, and **JobKeyword**. JobKeyword contains three fields: *Id*, *JobId* and *Keyword*, so every **Job** has its **JobKeyword**-s. How can I use SQL Server Full Text Search so it will query the Job table, with keywords from the JobKeyword table?

This is my current SQL:

```
WITH JobRN AS 
(
    SELECT TOP (@End) searchTable.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY searchTable.RANK) AS RowNum
    FROM FREETEXTTABLE([Job], *, @Keywords) AS searchTable 
    ORDER BY RANK
)

SELECT * FROM [Job]
INNER JOIN JobRN ON Job.Id = JobRN.[Key]
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @Start AND @End
ORDER BY [DATE]
```

Currently, it searches by all fields in the Job table. How can I change it so it will search by JobKeyword table (but returns Job results of course)?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not big with free text indexes but since no-one else has replied.

Without more details this is a bit of guess, but it sounds like you just want to replace
FREETEXTTABLE([Job], *, @Keywords)  with FREETEXTTABLE([JobKeyword], *, @Keywords).

But that assumes there is a freetext index on it.